# CheckboxList De-Selecting Issue using Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my CheckBoxList Design Code.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklst_assistance_seeking" runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chklst_assistance_seeking_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
<asp:ListItem Text="Mentoring" Value="Mentoring"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Seed Funding" Value="Seed Funding"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Assistance in Market Access" Value="Assistance in Market Access"></asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Text="Help with certification" Value="Help with certification">    </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Below is my checkboxlist select index change code.

```
   protected void chklst_assistance_seeking_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string assistance_seeking = "";
    Collection<string> items = new Collection<string>();
    for (int index = 0; index < chklst_assistance_seeking.Items.Count; index++)
    {
        if (chklst_assistance_seeking.Items[index].Selected)
        {
            items.Add(chklst_assistance_seeking.Items[index].ToString());
        }
    }
    assistance_seeking = String.Join(",", items.ToArray());

    string[] selectedvalues = assistance_seeking.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedvalues.Length; i++)
    {
        selectedvalues[i] = selectedvalues[i].Trim();
        if (selectedvalues[i].ToString() == "Help with certification")
        {
         pnl_assistance_seeking_help.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (selectedvalues[i].ToString() == "Other")
        {
         pnl_assistance_seeking_Other.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (selectedvalues[i].ToString() == "Mentoring")
        {
          pnl_assistance_seeking_Mentoring.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pnl_assistance_seeking_help.Visible = false;
            pnl_assistance_seeking_Other.Visible = false;
            pnl_assistance_seeking_Mentoring.Visible = false;

        }
    }

}
```

When I am selecting checkboxlist Item then panel is visible true correctly after one by one selecting, but when I am de-selecting checkboxlist item one by one then Panel is not visible false one by one. It visible false all of last de-selecting.

Comment: any logic, please help to out this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visibility of the panels is reset to false inside the loop, so that may happen for each iteration, which seems wrong. Also you won't reset the state of other panels if any of `if` statements is true.

I would suggest the following logic:

- Set all panels visibility to false before the loop
- Run the loop
- On each iteration probably change visibility of some panel to true, if condition is satisfied

That way you should always have panels visibility corresponding to the current state of check boxes. In code would look something like that:

```
pnl_assistance_seeking_IIGP_help.Visible = false;
pnl_assistance_seeking_IIGP_Other.Visible = false;
pnl_assistance_seeking_IIGP_Mentoring.Visible = false;

string[] selectedvalues = assistance_seeking_IIGP.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < selectedvalues.Length; i++)
{
    selectedvalues[i] = selectedvalues[i].Trim();
    if (selectedvalues[i].ToString() == "Help with certification")
    {
     pnl_assistance_seeking_IIGP_help.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (selectedvalues[i].ToString() == "Other")
    {
     pnl_assistance_seeking_IIGP_Other.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (selectedvalues[i].ToString() == "Mentoring")
    {
      pnl_assistance_seeking_IIGP_Mentoring.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: now panel is not visible true when I will select any item of check box list, please check. @Andrei